# CSS - Content gets pushed to the left only in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My [website](http://dandoes.net) passes both validation for both [XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http:%2F%2Fdandoes.net) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http:%2F%2Fdandoes.net). It looks fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, even IE 6 (alas, not IE 5.5 but who cares?). Why then, would everything be pushed all the way to the left in IE 7? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: WTH is going on with the formatting here?

Comment: No idea. Looks like a bug to me (looks fine in preview to you too, right?)

Comment: Yup, looks fine in preview... I tried changing the markdown to use the  [title](url) format, still no joy...

Comment: <% foreach(var channel in this.ViewData.Model.Channels) { %> <-- bugs in your /Social

Comment: Ah, thanks Filip... fixed now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i make a centered page i do the following;

set width for the "page"-div and fix margins and center the content in the body.

```
#page {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Has always worked fine for me in all browsers...

Comment: Using relative positioning on div#page allows child elements to be positioned absolutely relative to the div rather than the window.

Answer (score 0):

Put another div around everything in the `<body>` and set your margin and width styles on that div, rather than the body itself. Set `text-align: center;` on `<body>` as well.

```
<body> <!-- text-align: center -->
    <div id="container"> <!-- width 960px, margin 30px auto, text-align: left, position: relative -->
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="page"></div>
        <div id="preload"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's borked because you do positioning on body/html elements which is plain wrong and will never look the same on all the browsers. See: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/02/11/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/

Just use wrapper elements - NEVER position the body.

Comment: I'm confused... you say to NOT use styling on the body element, but then you post an article that says exactly the opposite... Besides, I wasn't positioning the body itself.